# How to pull data from git api?

Tags: javascript, git, api, version-control, github

Can anyone please help me understand this ? I am trying to follow the instruction from git api webpage in attempt to get some commits values from git api. ( I want to get all the branch names, username, commit_parent, and commit_date for all commits from the repository )

Here's below is their [instruction](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/)  :

[image]

so.. I installed git and I was able to clone and commit etc. , but say if I want to get some commits related info from this repo -> wesm/D3py what do I need to do exactly ?

I do not understanding how does `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/commits/:sha`  statement here work exactly ... ( sorry , if this is too dumb to ask )

GET /repos/wesm/D3py/git/commits/

I have tried to type this into CMD but it does not recognize "GET" where exactly do I need to put this command ? If I use JavaScript how exactly I use this command ?

Comment: Replace the /-separated parts starting with : by their respecting variables. Then issue a HTTP GET request on the resulting URL. Does that help you?

Comment: I got the variable part , but I'm not familiar with "HTTP GET" how exactly I issue this ? I'm new to HTTP , I have index.html where I have some JS in there. which program do I need to use to issue http get ?

Comment: Which programming language are you using? On the commandline, you can simply use `wget` without any special arguments. GET is default for almost any HTTP library/tool.

Comment: In python, you can use `urrlib2` or `requests` (the latter is usually easier, but its an external dependency)

Comment: i'm using javascript within HTML and D3library, I'm trying to pull this info to be used in D3. Is there a way i can use this in JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can simply use:

```js
$.get("https://api.github.com/repos/wesm/D3py/commits/master", function(data){
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
})
```

`.get` stands for the `GET` request type. The URL is simply an assembled from the string you gave above.

The code example simply alerts the JSON data.

Comment: Happy to help ;-) Note that you *might* have a problem with the same origin policy that prevents cross-domain requests, but I actually don't know enough about that policy to judge if it is really a problem in this case.